# How to handle a file upload with a many to one relationship in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, file-upload, doctrine-orm, many-to-one

I'm creating a ticket system for practice purposes.

Right now I'm having a problem with uploading files.

The idea is that a ticket can have multiple attachments, so I created a many-to-one relationship between the ticket and the upload tables.

```
class Ticket {

// snip

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Ticket", mappedBy="ticket")
 */
protected $uploads;

// snip
}
```

The upload entity class contains the upload functionality, which I took from [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html) tutorial:

```
<?php

namespace Sytzeandreae\TicketsBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Sytzeandreae\TicketsBundle\Repository\UploadRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="upload")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Upload
{
    /**
     * @Assert\File(maxSize="6000000")
     */
    private $file;

    private $temp;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Ticket", inversedBy="upload")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ticket_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $ticket;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $src; 

    public function getAbsolutePath()
    {
        return null === $this->src
            ? null
            : $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->src;
    }

    public function getWebPath()
    {
        return null === $this->src
            ? null
            : $this->getUploadDir().'/'.$this->src;
    }

    public function getUploadRootDir()
    {
        // The absolute directory path where uplaoded documents should be saved
        return __DIR__.'/../../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();
    }

    public function getUploadDir()
    {
        // Get rid of the __DIR__ so it doesn/t screw up when displaying uploaded doc/img in the view
        return 'uploads/documents';
    }

    /**
     * Sets file
     * 
     * @param UploadedFile $file
     */
    public function setFile(UploadedFile $file = null)
    {
        $this->file = $file;

        if (isset($this->path)) {
            // store the old name to delete after the update
            $this->temp = $this->path;
            $this->path = null;
        } else {
            $this->path = 'initial';
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get file
     *
     * @return UploadedFile
     */
    public function getFile()
    {
        return $this->file;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set title
     *
     * @param string $title
     */
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;
    }

    /**
     * Get title
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * Set src
     *
     * @param string $src
     */
    public function setSrc($src)
    {
        $this->src = $src;
    }

    /**
     * Get src
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getSrc()
    {
        return $this->src;
    }

    /**
     * Set ticket
     *
     * @param Sytzeandreae\TicketsBundle\Entity\Ticket $ticket
     */
    public function setTicket(\Sytzeandreae\TicketsBundle\Entity\Ticket $ticket)
    {
        $this->ticket = $ticket;
    }

    /**
     * Get ticket
     *
     * @return Sytzeandreae\TicketsBundle\Entity\Ticket 
     */
    public function getTicket()
    {
        return $this->ticket;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function preUpload()
    {
        if (null !== $this->getFile()) {
            // do whatever you want to generate a unique name
            $filename = sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
            $this->src = $filename.'.'.$this->getFile()->guessExtension();
        }
    }

    public function upload()
    {
        // the file property can be empty if the field is not required
        if (null === $this->getFile()) {
            return;
        }

        // move takes the target directory and then the target filename to move to
        $this->getFile()->move(
            $this->getUploadRootDir(),
            $this->src
        );

        // check if we have an old image
        if (isset($this->temp)) {
            // delete the old image
            unlink($this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->temp);
            // clear the temp image path
            $this->temp = null;
        }

        // clean up the file property as you won't need it anymore
        $this->file = null;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PostRemove
     */
    public function removeUpload()
    {
        if ($file = $this->getAbsolutePath()) {
            unlink($file);
        }   
    }
}
```

The form is build as follows:

```
class TicketType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title')
            ->add('description')
            ->add('priority')
            ->add('uploads', new UploadType())
    }
```

Where UploadType looks like this:

```
class UploadType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options) {
        $builder->add('file', 'file', array(
            'label' => 'Attachments',
            'required' => FALSE,
            'attr' => array (
                'accept' => 'image/*',
                'multiple' => 'multiple'
            )
        ));
    }
```

This part seems to work fine, I do get presented a form which contains a file uploader.

Once I put this line in the Ticket entity's constuctor: 
    $this->uploads = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
It throws me the following error:

> Neither property "file" nor method "getFile()" nor method "isFile()"
>   exists in class "Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection"

If I leave this line out, and upload a file, it throws me the following error:

> "Sytzeandreae\TicketsBundle\Entity\Ticket". Maybe you should create
>   the method "setUploads()"?

So next thing I did was creating this method, try an upload again and now it throws me:

> Class Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile is not a
>   valid entity or mapped super class.

This is where I am really stuck. I fail to see what, at what stage, I did wrong and am hoping for some help :)

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6930001/1847340)?

Comment: Yes, I did, altough not sure if I did that the right way. It still threw me the UploadedFile is not a valid entity error...

Comment: what is your `setUpload` method look like?

Comment: /**
     * Set uploads
     * 
     * @param Sytzeandreae\TicketsBundle\Enitity\Upload $uploads
     */
    public function setUploads($uploads)
    {
     $this->uploads = $uploads;
    }

Comment: Can you please what was the solution to this issue?

Comment: Actually I haven't been able to fix this yet. I stuck with one upload :(

Answer (score 0):

You can either add a [collection field-type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html) of `UploadType()` to your form. Notice that you can't use the multiple option with your current `Upload` entity ... but it's the quickest solution.

Or adapt your `Ticket` entity to be able to handle multiple files in an ArrayCollection and looping over them.