# How to get file array in Symfony controller?

Tags: php, symfony, orm

I've user Symfony for the my application service.  One service call  send file array (multiple files) in post. how can i get that?

because when I use  below code and `dump` `$uploadedFiles` is empty.  when send single image, it work,  any help?

```
public function createAction(Request $request) {
    $uploadedFiles = $request->files;    
}
```

this not about multiple file upload as [Multiple file upload with Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6736946/multiple-file-upload-with-symfony2)  question.  This is about how to get multiple files (file array) in Request

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple file upload with Symfony2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6736946/multiple-file-upload-with-symfony2)

Comment: This is about how to get multiple files (file array) in Request (API request)

Comment: i would image the issue is on the sending part, perhaps to do with the Content-Type header ?